# How to compare date and time in two separated fields with actual date-time (by JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

How by Javascript compare date and time in two datetimepicker fields with actual datetime? In other words I need to consider if date and time in my form is after or before Now.

I have two datetimepicker fields in my form:

[image]

(I am using datetimepicker on http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

Really not elegant way would be somethink like:

```
        var dateVal = $('#dtpckr-StartMainDateTime-Date').val();
        var timeVal = $('#dtpckr-StartMainDateTime-Time').val();
        var day = dateVal.toString().substr(0, 2);
        var month = dateVal.toString().substr(3, 2);
        var year = dateVal.toString().substr(6, 4);
        var hour = '00';
        var minute = '00';
        if (timeVal) {
            hour = timeVal.toString().substr(0, 2);
            minute = timeVal.toString().substr(3, 2);
        }
        var startDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute);
        var now = new Date();

        if (startDate > now) {
            console.log('future');
        }
        else {
            console.log('current or past');
        }
```

Comment: Please mention the relevant code with your try, and precise how a date can be compared (give some examples). It will help !

Comment: Ok, I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your dateTime into millisec
2. getCurrentMillis() and check if its greater, if so then its the end date validation. If its happening for start date then its an error and vizversa validation.

Hope you understood.